# Store base64 encoded PDF document to Sybase

Tags: java, sybase, jtds

I need to store base64 encoded document in Sybase database via stored procedure. I use JTDS driver.

As long as I am not trying to store my PDF document everything is fine. However as soon I attempt to path encoded string. I get the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: Sybase does not support char parameters > 255
>   bytes.

Here is the code

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

cs = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_save_pdf (?,?,?,?)}");
cs.setString(++i, id);
cs.setString(++i, source);
cs.setString(++i, base64EncodedDocument);   
cs.registerOutParameter(++i, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
cs.execute();
```

When Sybase Developers execute this procedure but they use JConnect driver. Here is my question does JTDS driver not support usage of long strings and I need to use JConnect or do I miss something in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Not familiar with Sybase, but CHAR often has that limitation, try TEXT or look whether BLOB exists, as bytes the data would be 33% smaller.

Comment: I have tried BLOBs, it didn't work since proc expects TEXT datatype. JTDS driver doesn't have setText method

Comment: SQL datatype TEXT instead of CHAR. From earlier types, CHAR was used for n chars in a record, and TEXT was a pointer to a MEMO field. Since then CHAR often is limited to 255 in the database, and TEXT can hold more. One can use setString in both.

Comment: See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278452897615.html - there is indeed a limit of 255 bytes, but not for LONGVARCHAR or TEXT.

Comment: Yes, I know therefore I tried to set character stream, like so cs.setCharacterStream(++i, new StringReader(base64EncodedDocument, base64EncodedDocument,.length());

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_save_pdf(... IN pdfcontent TEXT ...) ...`

Comment: It is already set as TEXT in proc

Comment: Then it just could be a check in `setString(int, String)` though I am afraid it is a stored procedure problem. Try `setCharacterStream(++i, new StringReader(base64));`

Comment: Sorry, my main attention was/is at my work. Maybe you need an other solution, a temp table or such. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with JTDS driver as soon as I switched to JConnect driver everything began to work as expected.